# how to create a PHP REST API Client to get the user logged in on the server?

Tags: php, api, rest, cookies, curl

i want to create a php web app with REST API.where user logins on the Server/Main site.
problem is that how to get current logged in user on a php client.i am using CURL at client to get data from server.
if i store a user cookie in browser when user logins on my site, then client can't access them
because CURL doesn't send cookies when requesting. if i use CURL COOKIEJAR or COOKIEFILE, they
will not safe since a client can store cookies data and use them for access user's account.
i want my API to be like Facebook API. how FB API knows who is currently logged in?
i only want to know is there any way to get the currently logged in user on server site.either by cookie or by session.
please someone help me
thanks

Comment: `if i use CURL COOKIEJAR or COOKIEFILE, they will not safe since a client can store cookies data and use them for access user's account.` if curl runs on the client's computer, *nothing* you do can be safe from the client, can it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook API and Twitter API uses Oauth
http://oauth.net/

Oauth is awesome for the man in the middle login. Oauth connect the user with the final server and to the server in the middle it gives a token, that token is the way to know who is logged.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/